# SSRS date default with formula disables parameter

Tags: date, reporting-services, parameters, default

When I set a default value formula for a date parameter in SSRS, such as:

```
=CDate(”01/” & Month(Now) & “/” & Year(Now))
```

or even:

```
=Now
```

the date parameter control becomes disabled with nothing in it. Does anyone know what simple thing (I am sure) I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

After playing some more, I realized that the date controls became enabled when I picked a value from a preceding dropdown parameter that did not have a default. Apparently, controls after non-default parameters are disabled until you pick something, so order matters.

From an MDSN article:

"parameter order is important when you want to show users the default value for one parameter before they choose values for other parameters"

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281392.aspx

Comment: That was a really nasty thing! Just disabling controls without any messages or warnings is a horrible thing to do. Shame on Microsoft. Thanks for the good catch and helping me fix my blasted report.

Comment: That's bad bad bad. Just started Reporting Services and thats not giving a good impression. I wonder how many other "rules" there we are supposed to magically know about?

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same and the problems lies on the USER ID parameter that I set to internal visibility but without any default value. When I put in default value or set this to null, the date parameter was enabled.. (User ID parameter comes before the date parameter on my case)

Answer (score -3):

`Now` is a function and you must use like `=Now()`

maybe it is your problem.

Comment: Change to =Now() did not fix the issue.

Comment: You maze well delete this answer. It has nothing to do with the calendar control getting disabled. I gave you a 3rd downvote so if you delete you can at least get the peer pressure badge.