# SSRS - Subtract 60 days from today and convert to Long

Tags: reporting-services, db2, ssrs-2012, db2-400

I have an SSRS report that queries the AS400. The query takes 2 parameters, `start_date` and `end_date`. So the report has two text `type` parameters.

I am trying to take today's date (using the `Today()` function), and do a `DateDiff` of 60 days, and use that value as the default value.

Here are the complications:

1. My `Start_Date` and `End_Date` parameter in the dataset are `integer` type variables, not `DateTime`.
2. That means, I cannot do a `DateAdd("d", -60, Today())`. Because then, that parameter is considered a date parameter, not an integer parameter. Passing that value to the query is not possible.
3. I cannot change the parameters' data type to `Date`. Again, the query is expecting an integer value. This is sending a date value (with / and everything).
4. I cannot cast the parameter in the query, because AS400 parameters are a PAIN to pass. So right now, the parameter is a `?`. There are 6 parameters in the query and are in the exact order as they are in the report. I don't know how a `CAST` or a `CONVERT` is going to work on a `?`.
5. The `Start_Date` and `End_Date` fields have this format: `YYYYMMDD`

Here is what I was thinking about doing:

1. I was thinking of doing a `CAST` on today's year, today's month, and today's date to `STR` and then concatenate them all.
2. And then, `CAST` that `STR` to `INT` and adding -60.

But if I did that, I am left with a completely random number. It may be anything. For instance, today's date minus 60 days would be `20170650`, which is obviously not a valid date.

How do I do this? Do I get today's date, add -60 days, then convert it to Integer? When I try to do that, I get a greyed out empty parameter textbox when I run the report. I thought that would work, I don't know why it does not.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

TL;DR:
How do I do a `DateAdd` of -60 days to Today's date and convert it to YYYYMMDD format and pass it as an `Integer` to the query?

Comment: `CAST`/`CONVERT` works just fine - the question mark is a _parameter marker_, which is replaced at eval time with the appropriate data.  If you're passing something in to a query (DB2, or any RDBMS), you **must** use them, or fall victim to SQL Injection.

Comment: Yes, but when I do it with SQL Server, I usually create a variable and use the variable as a parameter. That does not seem to be a possibility on DB2.

Comment: Doesn't matter; even your SQL Server variables are parameter markers, just friendlier ones (and some drivers for DB2 actually do permit named parameter markers).

Comment: That is very helpful, thank you. The question mark was really scary to me. I will try messing with it a bit. That might make this whole thing easier on me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is all done using SSRS functions. It might be easier and/or cleaner to write a function within your report to do this but I'll leave that to you.

This takes the current date, does a `DATEADD` of minus 60 days and picks the year, month and day from the result. It multiplies the year by 10000, the month by 100 and adds the day. You end up with an integer in the format YYYMMDD

Here's the expression (split onto a few lines for clarity)

```
=
(YEAR(dateadd(DateInterval.Day, -60, now())) * 10000) 
+ (Month(dateadd(DateInterval.Day, -60, now())) *100) 
+ day(dateadd(DateInterval.Day, -60, now()))
```

Comment: This seems like the way I'd like to go, I will try it out and let you know if it works. Thank you.

Comment: Can you think of any reasons why the entire parameter section disappears when I add your query as the default value of a parameter? I mean, there is a section on the top with the "View Report" button, but it does not show me any parameters

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541456/ssrs-date-default-with-formula-disables-parameter - WOW! That is apparently a "feature" of SSRS. I prefer the term BUG.

Comment: I've just tested this. I created a blank report added a single parameter, set the type to integer and set the default value expression to be the exact code above. When I run the report. The parameter appeared as expected with the correct value showing. I'm not sure why you don;t see the same. Try craeting a new report as I did to see if you can replicate it.

Comment: It was because I had more than one parameter and the date value default parameters are in the 3rd and 4th position. If there is a non-default parameter BEFORE a default parameter, SSRS expects you to enter a value for the non-default parameter before populating a value for the default. This is such a stupid design choice by Microsoft.

Comment: Wow, I've been writing reports in SSRS for years, and some pretty complex ones but I've never come across that, or maybe I got lucky several hundred times :)

Answer (score 1):

U can do :

```
select cast(replace(char(current_date - 60 day, ISO),'-','')as integer) from *your_table*
```

As you can see, the format is an integer, and you get : yyyyMMdd, u can after susbtract or add what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL way to do so would be

```
   year(current_date - 60 days) * 10000
    + month(current_date - 60 days) * 100  
    +   day(current_date - 60 days)
```

Personally, I prefer to have just a conversion function that takes a date and returns a numeric representation.

```
select * 
from mytable
where trndte 
  between ConvertToDte(current_date - 60 days)
      and ConvertToDte(current_date)
```

In fact, I usually use [Alan Campin - IDATE - iSeries Date Conversion](http://www.think400.dk/downloads.htm) tool, which is a set of UDFs the convert between date data types and numeric or character.

Comment: Alan's answer does what you just said on SSRS directly and I'd probably go with that. Thank you.